# Receive string message using BufferedReader and Images using DataInputStream in same socket

Tags: android, sockets, bufferedreader, datainputstream

I have two projects, one reads string messages using `BufferedReader` and the other reads images using `DataInputStream`. I want to merge these two projects to receive messages and images from the same socket, but I am confused how to do this as I am facing conflicts. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```java
//class to receive messages
class messageReceiver implements Runnable {     
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (s.isConnected()) {
            try {
                isr = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
                br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                mesg = br.readLine();
                mn.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(mn, "Message: "+mesg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

//this class is used to read byte arrays and converts into images
class imageReceiver implements Runnable {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    MainActivity mn;
    DataInputStream dis;
    byte[] data;

    public imageReceiver(MainActivity mn){
        this.mn = mn;
    }

    public int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b){
        final ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(b);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        return bb.getInt();
    }

    public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext , Bitmap inImage){
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(),inImage,"123"+Math.random(),null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(s.isConnected()) {
            try {
                InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
                dis = new DataInputStream(in);
                byte[] readMsgLen = new byte[4];
                dis .read(readMsgLen,0,4);
                final int length = byteArrayToInt(readMsgLen);
                data = new byte[length];
                dis.readFully(data,0,data.length);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

                mn.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(mn.getApplicationContext(), "Image received of length: "+length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        if (bitmap==null){
                            Toast.makeText(mn.getApplicationContext(), "Image is not received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(mn.getApplicationContext(), "Image received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Picasso.get()
                                    .load(getImageUri(mn,bitmap))
                                    .fit()
                                    //           .centerCrop()
                                    .into(mn.iv);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will never work. The `BufferedReader` will read ahead, stealing image data that you're trying to read with the `DataInputStream`. Get rid of the `BufferedReader`, and exchange the strings with `readUTF()/writeUTF()`.

Comment: you have any idea how can I use "if" with readUTF() to differentiate when to read byte array ?

Answer (score -1):

Your `messageReceiver` is misusing `BufferedReader`.  By creating a new `BufferedReader` on each loop iteration, you are discarding any bytes that have already been read from the socket into the reader's internal buffer but have not been by your code yet.  To avoid that loss, you need to create the `BufferedReader` before entering the loop.  You don't have that problem with your `imageReceiver` because it is not using any buffered I/O.

However, when sharing a single `InputStream` with multiple operations, any buffering done in one operation will end up reading bytes that the other operation needs.  That is why you are running into problems when you try to merge your projects together.  Your `BufferedReader` is reading bytes that your `DataInputStream` wants.  You need to move the buffering closer to the socket and then reuse the same buffer for both operations.

Try something more like this:

```java
Socket s = ...;

...

//class to receive messages and images
class mergedReceiver implements Runnable {     

    MainActivity mn;
    BufferedInputStream bis;

    String readLine() throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        do {
            int b = bis.read();
            if (b == -1)
                throw new IOException();

            if (b == 0x0D)
            {
                bis.mark(1);
                b = bis.read();
                bis.reset();

                if (b == -1)
                    throw new IOException();

                if (b == 0x0A)
                    break;

                bytes.write(0x0D);
            }
            else if (b == 0x0A)
                break;

            bytes.write(b);
        }
        while (true);

        return bytes.toString();
    }

    Bitmap readImage() throws IOException {
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

        // note: multi-byte integers are most commonly sent
        // over network communications using big endian instead!

        // final int length = dis.readInt();
        byte[] lenBytes = new byte[4];
        dis.readFully(lenBytes, 0, 4);
        final ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(lenBytes);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        final int length = bb.getInt();

        byte[] data = new byte[length];
        dis.readFully(data, 0, length);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, length);
    }

    public mergedReceiver(MainActivity mn){
        this.mn = mn;
    }

    public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "123"+Math.random(), null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream());

        while (s.isConnected()) {
            try {
                ...
                if (should read string message now) {
                    string mesg = readLine();
                    if (mesg != null) {
                        mn.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(mn, "Message: " + mesg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                ...

                if (should read image now) {                
                    Bitmap bitmap = readImage();
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        mn.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(mn.getApplicationContext(), "Image received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Picasso.get()
                                    .load(getImageUri(mn, bitmap))
                                    .fit()
                                    //           .centerCrop()
                                    .into(mn.iv);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                ...
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, when sending different types of data over a single socket connection, you should frame the data in such a way that the receiver can know up front what kind of data it is receiving.  You should change your sender (if possible) to prefix your strings and images with a common header that indicates the kind of data that follows it.  Then your receiver can read that header first, and then read and process the following data accordingly, eg:

```java
Socket s = ...;

...

//class to receive messages and images
class mergedReceiver implements Runnable {     

    ...

    @Override
    public void run() {
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

        byte[] msgLenBytes = new byte[4];
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(msgLenBytes);

        // note: multi-byte integers are most commonly sent
        // over network communications using big endian instead!
        byte[] msgLenBytes = new byte[4];
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(msgLenBytes);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

        int msgLength;
        byte[] msgData = null;

        while (s.isConnected()) {
            try {
                // read the message type...
                int msgType = bis.read();
                if (type == -1)
                    break;

                // read the message length...
                // msgLength = dis.readInt();
                dis.readFully(msgLenBytes, 0, 4);
                msgLength = bb.getInt(0);

                msgData = new byte[msgLength];
                dis.readFully(msgData, 0, msgLength);

                if (msgType == 1) { // string message
                    string mesg = new string(msgData, 0, msgLength);
                    mn.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(mn, "Message: " + mesg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                else if (msgType == 2) { // image
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(msgData, 0, msgLength);
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        mn.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(mn.getApplicationContext(), "Image received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Picasso.get()
                                    .load(getImageUri(mn, bitmap))
                                    .fit()
                                    //           .centerCrop()
                                    .into(mn.iv);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```